# Get a specific channel details from Slack using Postman

Tags: postman, slack, slack-api

It seems I can't filter my request, everytime I use the following get request:

```
https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?token=xoxp-112408&channel=random
```

I get a list of **all** the channels, but I want to get only a specific channel.

I tried the following inputs:

- random
- "random"
- C39MJU75F
- #random
- "C39MJU75F"

[image: screenshot from postman]

But no matter what, I always get all the channels, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conversations.list` will always return "all" channels. It's not possible to restrict the result, other then that you can select which type of channels you want (e.g. public channels or private channels).

If you want to get information for just one channel you can use [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info).

Example:

```
https://slack.com/api/conversations.info?token=TOKEN&channel=C12345678
```

Note that most conversations methods will want you to provide the channel ID, not the name.